# Micronaut "Referential integrity constraint violation" occurs during storing object with many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, h2, micronaut

I created simple service in Micronaut to handle book entities from Google Books API.
Book entities have relations many to many with Author and Category entities.

When I try to store Book entity a "Referential integrity constraint violation" occurs.

```
Hibernate: insert into book (description,language,page_count,preview_link,published_date,publisher,rating,subtitle,thumbnail_url,title,isbn) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into author (rating,name) values (?,?)
Hibernate: insert into category (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into category (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into books_authors (author_name,book_id) values (?,?)
18:20:28.480 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23506, SQLState: 23506
18:20:28.481 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Referential integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_4B: PUBLIC.BOOKS_AUTHORS FOREIGN KEY(BOOK_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.BOOK(ISBN) ('WIERZMA')"; SQL statement:
insert into books_authors (author_name,book_id) values (?,?)
```

Book (owning) enitity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Serdeable
@Entity(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ISBN", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 1024)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "subtitle", length = 1024)
    private String subtitle;

    @Column(name = "publisher")
    private String publisher;

    @Column(name = "publishedDate")
    private String publishedDate;

    @Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "LONGVARCHAR")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "pageCount")
    private int pageCount;

    @Column(name = "thumbnailURL")
    private String thumbnailUrl;

    @Column(name = "language")
    private String language;

    @Column(name = "previewLink")
    private String previewLink;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private double rating;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "books_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_name")
    )
    private Set<Author> authors;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "books_categories",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_name")
    )
    private Set<Category> categories;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this == obj || obj instanceof Book && this.id.equals(((Book) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 17;
        result = prime * result + id.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Author entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Serdeable
@Entity(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "authors", targetEntity = Book.class)
    @Column(name = "books")
    private Set<Book> booksList;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private double rating;

    public Author(String name, double rating) {
        this.name = name;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        rating = Double.isNaN(rating) ? 0.0 : rating;
        this.rating = this.rating == 0.0 && rating != 0.0
                ? rating
                : Double.parseDouble(df.format(this.rating + rating / 2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this == obj || obj instanceof Author && this.name.equals(((Author) obj).name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 17;
        result = prime * result + name.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Mapping BookDto to Book

```
    public static Book to(BookResponse bookDto) {
        Set<Author> authors = bookDto.authorsIds.stream().map(a ->
                new Author(a, bookDto.rating)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Category> categories = bookDto.categoriesIds.stream().map(Category::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return new Book(
                bookDto.id,
                bookDto.title,
                bookDto.subtitle,
                bookDto.publisher,
                bookDto.publishedDate,
                bookDto.description,
                bookDto.pageCount,
                bookDto.thumbnailUrl,
                bookDto.language,
                bookDto.previewLink,
                bookDto.rating,
                authors,
                categories);
    }
```

My setup:

- Java 21
- Micronaut 4.3.1
- Micronaut data 4.6.2
- H2 Database

I tried to setup the database using flyway but that didn't help.
I used the same setup in different repository build with Spring framework which works for me without issues.

Please help ;)